# How to replace all double quotes without a backslash ahead

Tags: java, regex, double-quotes

Assume I have a string like below:

```
String param = "[\"\\n\",\"\\t\",\"'\",\"\\\"\",\"\\\\\"]"
```

The output of System.out.println is:

```
"\n","\t","'","\"","\\"
```

I would like to replace double quotes which doesn't have a backslash ahead, or, in another word, I would like to have the System.out.println output like below:

```
\n,\t,',\",\\
```

So I used this pattern:

```
System.out.println(param.replaceAll("\\\\{0}\"", ""));
```

But I got this:

```
\n,\t,',\,\\
```

As you can see, the double quote with a backslash ahead is also replaced.
How can I prevent it from being replaced?

*Edit: Sorry about the square brackets. You may ignore them cause they have nothing to do with this question*

Comment: And what is the expected result for `"\\\""`?

Comment: I posted an answer that should support any double-quoted string literal with escape sequences.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match and remove `"` that are string literal qualifiers:

```
(?s)(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFn1zd/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL modifier (just in case the string literal can span across lines)
- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` immediately to the left of the current location
- `((?:\\{2})*)`  - Group 1: any 0+ conseuctive occurrences of 2 backslashes
- `"` - a double quote (string literal start)
- `([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - 0+ sequences of

    - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char
    - `[^"\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `\` and `"`
- `"` - a closing string literal double quote

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/RSQxUK):

```
String param = "[\"\\n\",\"\\t\",\"'\",\"\\\"\",\"\\\\\",\"\\\\\\\"\"]";
System.out.println(param);
// => ["\n","\t","'","\"","\\","\\\""]
String regex = "(?s)(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\{2})*)\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"";
param = param.replaceAll(regex, "$1$2");
System.out.println(param);
// => [\n,\t,',\",\\,\\\"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match a back slash with a *negative lookbehind*.

A negative lookbehind looks like this:

```
(?<!X)Y
```

It will match pattern `Y` only if pattern `X` does not exist immediately before pattern `Y`.

In your case, `X` is "a back slash without a backslash in front" and `Y` is `"`.

This is the regex you need:

```
(?<![^\\]\\)"
```

Java code:

```
System.out.println(param.replaceAll("(?<![^\\\\]\\\\)\"", ""));
```

By the way, you seem to have forgotten to remove the leading and trailing square brackets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah I realised that. Edited.

Comment: You cannot match string literals with such approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean by `string literals`? Can you give an example?

Comment: [It is a wrong approach](https://regex101.com/r/1TPCHp/6). See how that handles `"\\\""` string literal (that defines ``\"`` literal string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see. Thank you for pointing that out. I'll keep my answer as it is for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Regex:

```
"([^,]+)"
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1TPCHp/3/)

Try this code([Generated](https://regex101.com/r/1TPCHp/3/codegen?language=java)):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\"([^,]+)\"";
final String string = "[\"\\n\",\"\\t\",\"'\",\"\\\"\",\"\\\\\"]";
final String subst = "$1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

[Execute and See the Output here](http://tpcg.io/jRcwNr)

Comment: You are correct Wiktor. I only kept the given input string in mind. Let me see if I can make any improvements on it. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/1TPCHp/7) would work fine.

Comment: I doubt that can be generalized. It might work with the current string, but it won't work with [general cases of string literals](https://regex101.com/r/1TPCHp/8). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use just that for your code :

```
System.out.println(param.replaceAll("\"(.)\"", "$1").replaceAll("\\[\"(.*)\"\\]", "$1"));
```

Your string:

```
String param = "[\"\\n\",\"\\t\",\"'\",\"\\\"\",\"\\\\\"]";
```

All items are between double quotes. So the first replaceAll will replace quotes :

```
System.out.println(param.replaceAll("\"(.)\"", "$1"));
```

The output:

```
["\n,\t,',\",\\"]
```

To clean the start and end of string:

```
System.out.println(param.replaceAll("\"(.)\"", "$1").replaceAll("\\[\"(.*)\"\\]", "$1"));
```